# Limiting CUDA cores in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend for a classification problem. Is it possible to limit CUDA cores used by my program? I have managed to limit GPU memory usage to run multiple cuda enabled programs parallel, but I need to limit CUDA cores also.